# I'm trying to start_intellij but it gets stuck immediately with error:

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm not sure what exactly happened.
I have **intellij** 2018.3 and suddenly it got stuck.
I tried to restart it but then I get the following error msg in my shell:

> libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
>   ES2 Prism: Error - reported GLX version = 1.2
>       GLX version 1.3 or higher is required

I'm trying to debug it but inside **~/.IdeaIC2018.3/system/log** the log file shows something very old... as if its not the correct place of the log file??

So how whats the problem?
How can I debug it?

Thanks

**P.S**

I dont know if it make any sense but it seems that it all happened after i delete __cacache folder from ~/.npm to clear some space

Comment: Can you still run other Java apps on your system like NetBeans or JEdit?

Comment: JEdit is working yes..

Answer (score 0):

Oki, I noticed that intellij in the right bottom side gave a small warning

> "the version of java might be unstable.."

something like that.

The problem was that $JAVA_HOME was set to:
**JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/1.8.0.65**

once it was changed to **JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/1.8.0.151** it started to work again.

Comment: It's recommended to use the bundled JetBrains Runtime instead as it fixes a lot of known issues. Just download IntelliJ IDEA with the runtime included instead of using your system Java version. See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879.